# Dynamic conditional joins in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, coalesce

I'm trying to write perhaps a dynamic conditional statement in BigQuery to dynamically join tables based on certain conditions. It's possible to have 1 or many conditions for a single ID.
How do I dynamically 'filter' a series of ID conditions together (using Table 1, 2 and 3) to get to a set of masterProductIds in to my Final table?

**Table 1 - identification_table**

[image: Table 1 - identification_table]

**Table 2 - filing_table**

[image: Table 2 - filing_table]

**Table 3 - Price**

[image: Table 3 - Price]

In this situation we have 3 conditions to be evaluated for Id 1, 2 conditions for Id 2 and 1 condition for Id 3.

In a situation where we have a price condition as well, it should join to the price table and filter depending on the operator and value in table 1. As for product condition, I don't have to join on any tables, I just take the value as is in table 1.

What I'm expecting as my final result set.

**Final Table**

[image: Final Table]

What I've done as of now:

```
select masterProductId, row_number() over (partition by id ) sq
from `filing_table` p 
left join `identification_table` pc
on case when subject = 'brand' then p.brandName when subject='category' then categoryName end = pc.boundaryValue
--on p.brandName = pc.boundaryValue or p.categoryName = boundaryValue
left join `price` pp
on p.code = pp.code
where 1=1
and pc.code = 'Id 2'
--and pp.RRP < safe_cast(pc1.boundaryValue as float64)
```

This would evaluate everything as a whole. I can't figure how to evaluate the IDs in a set by set basis.

Comment: very interesting "challenge" - are you flexible for some changes in your setup - 1) change column names in Table2 so they match values of column subject in Table1 2) replacing values of Table1 operator column to respective BigQuery operators - like `=` instead of `is equal` ; `<` instead of `less than` etc. ?

Comment: I can't change column names in Table2 to match values of subject in Table 1  2.) there's flexibility to replace the values of operators but preferably in a temp or staging table

Comment: so, in this case you might able to change values of Subject column to match column names of table2 - right? and all the `preferably in a temp or staging table` can be handled then as it is not a focus of your problem- agree? you/we need to focus on main challenge here and leave everything else for later on tuning/adjusting etc. Meantime, check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yes your assumptions are correct and that sounds like a plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and assumes tables to be set as below (with agreement from the OP in the comments to question)

`identification_table`

```
  SELECT 'Id 1' id, 'masterProductId' subject, '=' operator, '1007' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Id 1', 'brandName', '=', 'brand p' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Id 1', 'categoryName', '=', 'category 1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Id 2', 'categoryName', '=', 'category 1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Id 2', 'price', '<', '130'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Id 3', 'categoryName', '=', 'category 3'
```

`filing_table`

```
  SELECT 11 code, 'category 1' categoryName, 'brand p' brandName, 1001 masterProductId UNION ALL
  SELECT 22, 'category 1', 'brand z', 1002 UNION ALL
  SELECT 33, 'category 2', 'brand c', 1003 UNION ALL
  SELECT 44, 'category 2', 'brand v', 1004 UNION ALL
  SELECT 55, 'category 3', 'brand e', 1005
```

`price`

```
  SELECT 11 code, 3 price UNION ALL
  SELECT 22, 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 33, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 44, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 77, 28
```

So, below extracts from `filing_table` those `masterProductId`'s which qualify based on all criteria from `identification_table`

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT masterProductId
FROM (
  SELECT f.*, price
  FROM `filing_table` f
  LEFT JOIN `price` p
  USING(code)
)
WHERE ''' || (  
  SELECT STRING_AGG('(' || condition || ')', ' OR ')
  FROM (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT('(%s %s %s)', subject, operator, value), ' AND ') condition
    FROM `identification_table`,
    UNNEST([IF(subject IN ('price', 'masterProductId'), value, '"' || value || '"')]) value
    GROUP BY id
  ));
```

If to apply to sample data as in top of the answer  - output is

```
Row masterProductId  
1   1001     
2   1002     
3   1005
```

Comment: thanks Mikhail for this answer it satisfies my conditions but how do I persist this result in a table using a ```create or replace table `dataset.finalTable` as``` statement, or save it as a view and then just use a select statement on the view? because this execute statement produces 2 results.

Comment: just add `create or replace table \`dataset.finalTable\`` right before select statement as you would do with static query.